# Passing messages to content script from background

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tabs, sendmessage

In my extension, I am passing message from my `background.js` to `content.js` using `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`. For a valid `tabId` (I print its value, its non-negative), sometime content prints the alerts after the alert in `background.js` but not most of the times. Here is the sample code. Am I missing something in the code? Am expecting, each time the alert is displayed in `background.js`, there must be an alert in `content.js`. I am sending message when the request is being processed and the page is not yet displayed fully.

background.js

```
...

if(url == "http://example.com"){
   alert("In background");
   chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {msg: "HELLO"});          
}

...
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function (request, sender, sendResponse) {    
          alert("In content");
        });
```

manifest.json

```
  "content_scripts": [  
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://*/*",
                "https://*/*"
            ],
            "js": ["content.js"],
            "all_frames": true,
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
```

**Added**

Just to remind you, I want to change image URLs in DOM to http (from http to force redirect to http) after first time requests, redirected to https in `onBeforeRquest`, fail. This is not working as I realized content script is not receiving all the messages. As simple test in the following code, I am expecting each time the message "In onErrorOccurred" is printed, it must be followed by "In content" at console, but it is not working this way. Any suggestions are welcomed. I am first confirming if the content is ready, then send the message. Here is the code:

content.js:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({contentStatus: "activated"});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
   function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
      console.log(request.srcurl);  //or console.log("In content");
});
```

background.js:

```
var contentActive = {}  
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {   
   chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tabs) {       
      if (request.contentStatus == "activated")
          contentActive[tabs.id] = true;    
   });    
});

chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(
   function(details){ 
      if(details.type == 'image' && details.url == "https://example.com/image1.jpg") {     
         if(contentActive[details.tabId]){
           console.log("In onErrorOccurred");
              chrome.tabs.sendMessage(details.tabId, {srcurl: "In content"});       
        }
     }
}, {urls: ['https://*/*']});
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. I believe you should always see alert from the background page. if you quick enough to close it before webpage document loaded you will not see the alert from the content script at all. Also you could see alerts from each iframe on the page (if any). Not sure how you trigger the even in the background page but you could just notice delayed alert from these frames before you background code started to execute

Comment: @Andrey Am sending URL of the failed sub-resource from background and replacing (by modifying DOM) in content. This does not happen every time a request fails. The alert is for debugging and is not printed by content even if I use console.log. Moreover, it some time shows the alert from content.

Comment: So to clarify: do you see output (alert or console) from background page but not always see output from content scripts? Most likely reason is that content script does not setup onMessages listener (you background page sends message before this happens)

Comment: Yes. I dont understand by '..content script does not setup onMessages listener...'. I believe, `run_at` set to `document_end`, should be sufficient to inject content (make the listeners ready and should listen) before resources are loaded. I am triggering message sending in background when a sub-resource response is received.

Comment: Chrome guarantee the point after which it loads your scrips, but it does offer any guarantee when you script will be really loaded. To ensure your onMessage handler is set up before your call you need to send message from content script to the background page

Comment: @Andrey I did what you had suggested. I am confirming if the content script is ready by receiving message in `background.js` then send the message to content, but it is still not printing the message at the console.

Comment: It is hard to make any guess now for me. Please provide more code

Comment: @Andrey Added some more details. Thanks for your help.

Comment: 1) Move `chrome.extension.sendRequest({contentStatus: "activated"});` AFTER OnMessage listener attached. 2) tabId should be cleared from contentActive if user updated the tab. Does your script do this?

Comment: @Andrey 'your script', you mean my content script? I am not clearing the `contentActive` anywhere. What is the logic behind 1 and 2 ? If I have only one tab opened, each time the `onErrorOccurred` is triggered by an image request (this ensures the content is active now by `"run_at": "document_end"`) and the single tab ensures the content script is active only for this one tab.

Comment: Yes, I meant your script. Logic for 1: You send "activated" message before really set up the listener. No guarantee if works correctly because sendMessage asynchronous. You background script could send message back to page before listener is ready. 2) Each time you navigated to the new url tabid remains the same. Thus your scrip could sendMesage to the tab before it really refreshed with new content scripts